# Issues with struts2-jaxb-plugin

Tags: struts2, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to generate xml file from Struts action object. So that I have tried to use the plugin named struts2-jaxb-plugin. Infact I am new to this and they have given an example to how to use the JAXB plugin in struts2. [Click here](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jaxb-plugin/) to see the example what I have tried.

While starting the server, it gives the following Exception.

```
INFO - Could not locate any XML to UnMarshall an object from. Attempted using the parameter jaxbXML
23 Jan, 2012 1:12:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.struts2.result.jaxb.JAXBResultType.isGzipOkay(JAXBResultType.java:213)
at org.apache.struts2.result.jaxb.JAXBResultType.prepareForResponse(JAXBResultType.java:113)
at org.apache.struts2.result.jaxb.JAXBResultType.doExecute(JAXBResultType.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:362)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:266)
```

...

I am using the following jars in my project:

> xwork-core-2.1.6.jar,
>   struts2-core-2.2.1.jar

JAXB-plugin jar: `struts2-jaxb-plugin.jar`

Thanks in advance friends!

Comment: This means that given method is  missing in the classpath.Do you have only these three jars related to struts2?

Comment: No Umesh I have all jars related to struts2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this Plugin is writen for an older version Struts 2.0.x and is not compatible for newer versions like 2.1.x or higher.

Comment: Thanks friend, yeah that is the exact problem.